# Aceess a methods docstring without instance, Python

Tags: python, docstring

In Python, how can I access a docstring on a method without an instance of the class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `__doc__`:

```
class Test():
    def test_method(self):
        """I'm a docstring"""
        print "test method"


print Test.test_method.__doc__  # prints "I'm a docstring"
```

Or, [getdoc()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.getdoc) from `inspect` module:

> `inspect.getdoc(object)`
>
> Get the documentation string for an object,
>   cleaned up with cleandoc().

```
print inspect.getdoc(Test.test_method)  # prints "I'm a docstring"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`help()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#help) here:

```
>>> class Test:
...     def foo(self, bar):
...             """ Returns the parameter passed """
...             return bar
... 
>>> help(Test.foo)
```

Returns:

```
Help on method foo in module __main__:

foo(self, bar) unbound __main__.Test method
    Returns the parameter passed
(END)
```